# Phonegap 5.4.1 icons and build issues

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am developing an app using phonegap 5.4.1, I found out that there is a overall new documentation for adobe phonegap. I have gone through that and I have created the app using CLI as per documentation see the link below http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/3-create-your-app/cli/ and it has been created successfully. While running the app I have installed "Phonegap Developer App" in my device and through this app I can run my app. Check below
http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/4-run-your-app/cli/
Now my enquiry is, how can I store my app in the device, as its not getting stored anywhere and if I need to send apks to other device how can I accomplish that. Need help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**.
Since this appears to be your first post on this subject.
Is this your first hybrid App?
What is your target platform and their target versions? Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9?
What platform are you developing on? Windows, MacOS?
Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link.
Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an apk with the CLI

```
cordova build android --release
```

This will create a debug version that can be run on developer unlocked phones.

You'll need to sign it if you intend to upload it to the Play Store: [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)